# How to run some code when java servlet is deployed on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I have simple Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/doCourseRegister" })
public class DoCourseRegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
.....
}
```

I need to run some code when servlet is first created(or deployed) on Tomcat server. How to do it?

Should I use servlet constructor?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html

Comment: Have you tried the init method to see if it gets triggered?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener in web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>Your class</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Your class should implement `HttpSessionListener`.

Comment: Can you please explain how listener is attached to servlet?

Comment: I use annotations `WebListener` and `@WebServlet` and I don't know how to add listener to servlet?

Comment: If  you know org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener,using the same method to use it.